# Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference':type:value deserializer of type jackson.databind..EnumDeserializer does not support them

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, spring-data-rest

Getting error from Jackson and Tomcat libraries **Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': type: value deserializer of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer does not support them** when trying to save File entity in db through POST request. There is no Variable of type ENUM in the entity i'm trying to save and getting same error when firing POST request with empty JSON body.

I'm using Springboot version 2.4.1, Jackson libraries version 2.11.3.

POST Request i'm using:

```
{
"name": "test-spring-upgrade6",
"description": "This file is created for testing spring upgrade",
"fileMetadataId": 467802,
"filepath": "s3://test/2021.04.22-165922.963-4368861489768003962/",
"fileType": "http://file-management-service.aws-eks.com/api/v1/ui/files/74604"
 }
```

Not sure if there is any wrong with the code.Please help me get through this issue.

File.groovy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file", schema = "file_management")
class File {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_seq")
    @Column(name = "file_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "file_id_sequence", name = "file_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    public Integer fileId

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_type_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    FileType fileType

    String name

    String description

    @Column(name = "file_metadata_id")
    Integer fileMetadataId

    @FileExists (message = "error: the file does not exist.")
    @Column(name = "filepath")
    String filepath

    @Column(name = "createdt", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    Date createdt

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate(){
        this.createdt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = fileRegistrationJobEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    List<FileRegistrationJobEntity> registrationJobs    

}
```

FileType.groovy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file_type", schema = "file_management")
class FileType{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_type_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "file_type_id_sequence", name = "file_type_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    public Integer fileTypeId
    
    @NotNull
    String name
    
    @NotNull
    @Deprecated
    Integer fileTemplateId


    @Column(name = "createdt", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    Date createDt

    @Transient
    String latestSuccessfulActivationTimestamp;


    @PrePersist
    void onCreate(){
        this.createDt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    }

    @Column(name = "updatedt", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @LastModifiedDate
    Date updateDt


    @PreUpdate
    void onUpdate(){
        this.updateDt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fileType")
    List<fileIncludeColumns> includeColumns

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileType")
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    List<File> fileInstances

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_type_id")
    List<FileTypeSlaAssociation> fileTypeSlaAssociation



    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="operation_type", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    FileTypeOperation fileTypeOperation 
 

    public FileTypeOperation getFileTypeOperation() {
        if(this.fileTypeOperation == null) {
            return FileTypeOperation.MATCHING
        }

        return fileTypeOperation
    }
}
```

FileRepository.groovy

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(path="files", itemResourceRel="files")
interface FileRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<File, Integer>{

@RestResource(exported=true)
File save (File)

}
```

StackTrace of error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': type: value deserializer of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer does not support them
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer.findBackReference(JsonDeserializer.java:381) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase._resolveManagedReferenceProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:817) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:511) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:481) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:497) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:458) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:181) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:665) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:508) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:491) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4713) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4522) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3521) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar!/:2.11.3]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:274) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:246) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.lambda$read$6(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:202) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:202) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:132) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.4.2.jar!/:3.4.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

Tried saving file entity though REST controller by adding POST method to path. But still facing same issue.

StackTrace of logs when tried using REST Controller instead of Repository Rest resource.

```
2021-04-25 23:30:06.653  WARN 5260 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.test.core.entities.XrefFile]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': type: value deserializer of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer does not support them

23:30:06.665 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] ERROR com.test.application.exception.handler.CatchAllHandler - Unexpected Exception caught by com.test.application.exception.handler.CatchAllHandler
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
```

Comment: `FileType` seems to be the issue.

Comment: But i'm able to save the fileType through POST call. Will Update the File type too in the question.

Comment: @GSSwain Added Filetype too. Tried using REST controller using HTTP POST method. to save file entity in db but getting same error.

Comment: Found the issue. Issue is one of our gradle dependencies have JsonManagedReference on ENUM field in entity. Removed JsonManagedReference  and issue got resolved.